# base64 converted photo from Graph displays as broken image

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, node-request

I've racked my brain (and others) trying to get this to work. I am pulling a photo via MS Graph API - this part works fine. I am able to receive the data (as bytes). However, I can't get the image to convert properly to be attached as a file and posted.

I have read several postings on SO and GH as well as having tried ~10 different npm packages and flavors(btoa, atob, etc...out of desperation), including the JS example from the [Graph docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get). No solution has worked. The npm packages all produce different outputs from one another and none of them match the output when I take the photo and upload to an online base64 converter. In addition, if I take the online conversion and place the output string directly into the code, it works.

Here is the current iteration of my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var optionsPhoto = {
  url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token
  }
};

await request(optionsPhoto, function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    photoResponse.data = [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
        contentBytes: body.split(",").toString("base64"),
        contentLocation: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value",
        isinline: true,
        Name: "mypic.jpg"
      }
    ];
    photoResponse.ContentType = response.headers["content-type"].toString();
    photoResponse.Base64string = (
      "data:" +
      photoResponse.ContentType +
      ";base64," +
      photoResponse.data[0].contentBytes
    ).toString();
  } else {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

The `.sendActivity` command takes the attachment only as seen below:

```
await dc.context.sendActivity({
  attachments: [
    { contentType: photoResponse.ContentType, contentUrl: photoResponse.Base64string }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you request the photo's `/$value`, the response will simply be the image's raw binary. The `request` client however treats the body as a `utf8` based string by default.

In order to retrain the raw binary value, you need to explicitly tell `request` that you don't want this to happen. This is done by setting `encoding: null`. From the documentation:

> `encoding` - encoding to be used on `setEncoding` of response data. If `null`, the `body` is returned as a `Buffer`. Anything else **(including the default value of `undefined`)** will be passed as the [encoding](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) parameter to `toString()` (meaning this is effectively `utf8` by default). (**Note:** if you expect binary data, you should set `encoding: null`.)

The code would look something like this:

```
var optionsPhoto = {
  url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value",
  encoding: null, // Tells request this is a binary response
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token
  }
};

await request(optionsPhoto, function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Grab the content-type header for the data URI
    const contentType = response.headers["content-type"];

    // Encode the raw body as a base64 string
    const base64Body = body.toString("base64");

    // Construct a Data URI for the image
    const base64DataUri = "data:" + contentType + ";base64," + base64Body;

    // Assign your values to the photoResponse object
    photoResponse.data = [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
        contentBytes: base64Body,
        contentLocation: optionsPhoto.url,
        isinline: true,
        Name: "mypic.jpg"
      }
    ];
    photoResponse.ContentType = contentType;
    photoResponse.Base64string = base64DataUri;
  } else {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: You, sir, are a lifesaver! I have a presentation today and having this is a necessity. Thank you very much.